# Trying to switch between different video variants based on ViewportWidth

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, html5-video, codepen

web coding and optimization newbie here.

So, I was reading this tutorial detailing how to make hero videos faster and more responsive.

This version of the code has a simple web page with a large header video and some other elements. In JS, it checks the viewport width in order to change the `src` to either the desktop or mobile version of the video.

```
The HTML looks like this:
<header>   
<h1>
      My Shop
      <span class="width-display" id="width-display">TBD</span>
    </h1>
  </header>
<video
  class="full-width-video" id="hero-video"
  playsinline muted loop autoplay
  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/94aeb0f1-3796-4bdf-acdd-ccba5a23cfbf%2Fdesktop.mp4?v=1"
  data-src-mobile="https://cdn.glitch.me/94aeb0f1-3796-4bdf-acdd-ccba5a23cfbf%2Fmobile.mp4?v=1"
  data-src-desktop="https://cdn.glitch.me/94aeb0f1-3796-4bdf-acdd-ccba5a23cfbf%2Fdesktop.mp4?v=1">
    <div class="video-error">Uhoh, no video for you.</div>
</video>
  <p>..</p>
</body>
```

And, the JS like this:

```
const DESKTOP_BREAKPOINT = 480;
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  let heroVideoEl = document.getElementByID("hero-video");
  let heroVideoSrc = heroVideoEl.dataset.srcMobile
  let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (viewportWidth >= DESKTOP_BREAKPOINT) {
    heroVideoSrc = heroVideoEl.dataset.srcDesktop;
  }
  heroVideoEl.src = heroVideoSrc;
})
```

So, the problem is that this works perfectly in CodePen. If I open the Pen on my mobile, the mobile version of the video loads.

But, if I export the code, it no longer changes the `src` to load the mobile version. I checked to see that the JS is referenced correctly, and it is because I can add new elements to the DOM and do other manipulations.

Here is the HTML for the exported CodePen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Unoptimized</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<header>   
<h1>
      My Shop
      <span class="width-display" id="width-display">TBD</span>
    </h1>
  </header>
<video
  class="full-width-video" id="hero-video"
  playsinline muted loop autoplay
  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/94aeb0f1-3796-4bdf-acdd-ccba5a23cfbf%2Fdesktop.mp4?v=1"
  data-src-mobile="https://cdn.glitch.me/94aeb0f1-3796-4bdf-acdd-ccba5a23cfbf%2Fmobile.mp4?v=1"
  data-src-desktop="https://cdn.glitch.me/94aeb0f1-3796-4bdf-acdd-ccba5a23cfbf%2Fdesktop.mp4?v=1">
    <div class="video-error">Uhoh, no video for you.</div>
</video>
  <p>...</p>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
const DESKTOP_BREAKPOINT = 480;
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  let heroVideoEl = document.getElementById("hero-video");
  let heroVideoSrc = heroVideoEl.dataset.srcMobile;
  let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (viewportWidth >= DESKTOP_BREAKPOINT) {
    heroVideoSrc = heroVideoEl.dataset.srcDesktop;
  }
  heroVideoEl.src = heroVideoSrc;
})
```

I don't get any other errors using a debugger or in Google's developer console. It just refuses to swap the video `src` like it does in CodePen.

I am trying to use JavaScript to change a `video` elements `src` to use the correct variant of a video based on the `viewportwidth`.

Despite the rest of the JavaScript working and no errors (and it works in CodePen), it refuses to switch to the mobile video when I run it on my own website.